# Saving a long string in csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have string like:

```
str1 = "1 2 1 ... 1 2 2, 2 2 1 ... 1 1 2" # The ellipses(...) are just for representing that the string is very long.
```

I am saving it in a csv file like this:

```
myFile = open('file.csv','w')
myFile.write('CellA, CellB') # "CellA" and "CellB" are stored in separated cells
myFile.write('\n')
myFile.write(str1) # Parts(not char by char) of str1 are stored in multiple cells but the string appears to be written perfectly in Notepad++.
myFile.write('\n')
myFile.close()
```

I am able to get this fine:

```
CellA CellB   # Where CellA and CellB are written in two separate cells
```

I want str1 string to be stored in similar fashion with ',' as the delimiter like:

```
1 2 1 ... 1 2 2    2 2 1 ... 1 1 2 # '1 2 1 ... 1 2 2' and '2 2 1 ... 1 1 2' should be stored in two separate cells.
```

This method is working for 'CellA, CellB' but not for str1. Why is that and how can I fix this?

**Edit:**
The actual string is very long: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1X0SHwBFlZNcFGw4jbdRAF-MY2D5YV-syRYbbU2J1zpc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: are you sure the string doesnt have any other commas?

Comment: @RNar Yes completely sure. I can provide the actual string.

Comment: do that, then it can be replicated and maybe fixed

Comment: `This method is (not working) for str1` define `not working`

Comment: @RNar added the link to a file containing the string.

Comment: @njzk2 I have already defined "not working". Please read the comments in the code. str1 substrings are being written in multiple cells which is different than the required result as stated in my question above the "Edit" portion.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried playing around with python's csv module?

ex:

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

from [Python csv library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: Yes but I don't understand why this method isn't working. "CellA" and "CellB" are perfectly storing in two separate cells but that isn't the case with str1.

Comment: are you sure it is not a problem caused by quotation marks? @BlackDragon

Comment: Can you please tell what you mean by "quotation marks" here? @Liam

Comment: I don't think there is any problem with that. I have added a link to a file containing the actual string. I have a csv file containing a similar string. When I open it in notepad++ it also appears like "1 2 3 .. 4 5 6, 7 8 9 ... 10 11 12" and when I open that file in excel "1 2 3 .. 4 5 6" and "7 8 9 ... 10 11 12" are in two separate cells. However, with str1 the case is that it appears "1 2 1 ... 1 2 2, 2 2 1 ... 1 1 2" in notepad++ but in excel sub strings of it are stored in multiple cells in the excel file. @Liam